# how to move files based on size using .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I am new here. I Want to create batch file to move all file less then 3kb to another folder.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried any code? Stack Overflow isn't a 'write my code for me' site, please first show evidence of any research done first.

Answer (score 0):

Here a part of the code :

```
@echo off

set "$limit=3000"


for /f %%a in ('dir /a-d/b') do (
   if %%~za leq %$Limit% (echo %%~nxa Smaller/equal than %$limit% --^> %%~za Octets) else (
        echo %%~nxa Bigger than %$Limit% --^> %%~za Octets))
```

Just set the correct limit (in octets) for you and put a `move` at the right place.

Comment: As is, this will also move the .bat file itself, unless it exceeds the limit. I realize this is just a snippit, so I'm mentioning to save others who might've tried running this, like I did.

Answer (score 0):

Test this: launch it in the folder and make sure the target folder exists already.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*) do if %%~za LEQ 3000 move "%%a" "d:\new folder"
```